# Query the sum of a product

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write a query that returns the sum of two multiplied cells, where the name is equal to a person's name.  Let's say I  say I have:

| Name | score | days|
|---------|------|------|
| Suzie | 5.0 | 3    
| Jonny | 5.0 | 1  
| Suzie | 4.0 | 1    
| Suzie | 5.0 | 7    
| Jonny | 4.0 | 1

basically, I want to know Suzie's average score. Some rows represent multiple days though.  The arithmetic would be

(5.0 * 3)
+  (4.0 * 1)
+   (5.0 * 7)

I want to write a query:

```
=(index(query({a1:c3}, "Select Sum(Col2 * Col3) where Col1 = '" & D22 & "'"),2))
```

However, it doesn't like the part that says "Sum(Col2 * Col3)"

Is it possible to do the sum of two columns multiplied?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yup. Impossible. `SUM` requires a column identifier in `QUERY` and there's no workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a query.

---

> sum of two multiplied cells, where the name is equal to a person's name

Use SUMPRODUCT(array1, [array2, ...]):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B5,C1:C5,A1:A5=D22)
```

Notice that `A1:A5=D22` is a criterion.

---

> average score

Use SUMIF(range, criterion, [sum_range]):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B5,C1:C5,A1:A5=D22)/SUMIF(A1:A5,D22,C1:C5)
```

Answer (score 10):

Please see this [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mnm2wA8LjMr14TSewHLR0J_ooQqvlAmKHHeYiDg_WC4/edit).

**Data**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
a         10     20
a         30     40
b         10     30
```

**Result**

```
a   1400
b   300
```

**Formula**

`=QUERY({A2:A,ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B*C2:C)},
"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1")`

Comment: It's very satisfying to see how to do what I was trying to do (same as OP), but the accepted answer is so much more simple.